# Connect to ec2 database from non-local without tunneling

Tags: database, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am making some application and I need to connect to database which is on Amazon server.
It works fine from local but I need direct access to database without ssl tunneling.
On AWS console 3306 port is opened

Comment: What exactly is your question? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I have made it, edited config file /mysql/my.cnf, putted bind address to be 0.0.0.0 Using mysql to answer your question.